# Why am I getting an infinite loop in my printList() method of my linked lists assignment?

Tags: java, while-loop, linked-list, nodes, infinite-loop

Here is the code for my printList() method:

```
public String printList() { 

String list = "";
Node tempnode = headNode;

while (tempnode != null) {

  list = list + tempnode.data + ", ";
  tempnode = tempnode.next;

}

return list;
}
```

I am calling the method with System.out.println(myList.printList()); in my main.
When I call the method, the list itself is correct, but the list is printed an infinite amount of times and I can't figure out why. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It seems that the cause is outside the code you've posted, as we know this method can't be in an infinite loop, since you're able to print its output.

Comment: Your linked list is a "circular linked list" :D https://wiki.c2.com/?CircularLinkedList (or contains one)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to try to [solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: If this is the only code, `temp.next` is`temp` itself. It must be printing the same data over and over.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is circular (as @josejuan mentioned), then this should fix the problem.

```
public String printList() 
{ 
    String list = "";
    Node tempnode = headNode;

    while (tempnode != null)
    {

        list = list + tempnode.data + ", ";
        tempnode = tempnode.next;

        if ( tempnode == headNode )
        {
            break;
        } 
    }

    return list;
}
```